# Portal issue - Download "devices" file from command line

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In "Devices" --> Device list --> click the sprocket on the right --> **Download CSV** - then I can download (manually) my list of devices using my web browser. 
Is there a way to download the file via command line?
I tried to use Curl with no luck.

```
/curl -sslv3 -v -u gili.XXX "https://control.softlayer.com/device/device/downloaddevices?sort=#####......"
Enter host password for user 'gili.XXX':
* Trying 66.228.118.118...
* Connected to control.softlayer.com (66.228.118.118) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: none
* SSLv3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to control.softlayer.com:443
* Closing connection 0
```

I also tried links, links2, wget... They all complain regarding SSL problem.

Please advice...

Gili

Answer (score 0):

They don't support SSLv3, only TLS 1.0-1.2 so you will need to remove the `-sslv3` flag.  Additionally, you'll need to log in and maintain a session with them (via cookies), not HTTP auth with the `-u` option.

I can't test it but you might be able to pull it off all in one command like this:

```
curl -L -d username=youruser -d password=yourpass \
--cookie-jar cookies.txt --cookie cookies.txt \
https://control.softlayer.com/device/device/downloaddevices?sort=.....
```

The `-d` parameters make curl do a form post sending username and password fields (these are from their login form).  The cookie parameters are probably not needed since it will probably log you in and redirect to the CSV download but if you need to issue one curl request to log in, and another to download you'll need them.

Comment: Hi, I tried in several ways, all end up failing.
` ./curl --tlsv1.1 -v -L -d username=gili.lapid --cookie-jar cookies.txt --cookie cookies.txt   "https://control.softlayer.com/device/device/downloaddevices?sort=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22fullyQualifiedDomainName%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%5D&itemCountPerPage=148"
*   Trying 66.228.118.118...
* Connected to control.softlayer.com (66.228.118.118) port 443 (#0)
* Unsupported SSL protocol version
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unsupported SSL protocol version
`

Comment: What curl and openssl version do you have?  Typically just leave off any SSL/TLS options and let the client/server negotiate the best option.

Comment: The same... 
 ./curl -v -u gili.lapid "https://control.softlayer.com/device/device/downloaddevices?sort=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22fullyQualifiedDomainName%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%5D&itemCountPerPage=148"
Enter host password for user 'gili.lapid':
*   Trying 66.228.118.118...
* Connected to control.softlayer.com (66.228.118.118) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello.